# How to configure rewrite rules for small api using nginx?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, nginx, url-rewriting, rules

I'm new to [nginx](http://nginx.org/) and have a question in regards to rewrite rules. I'm trying to configure the rewrite rules for a very small API, is there in any way a more suitable way of doing this than what I have come up with?

I will have PHP running behind it, using a kind MVC workflow where the controller, method and argument will be taken from the URI, but the first param will represent the API key.

PHP concept:

```php
controller->method( arguments )
```

Configuration:

```
location /api/ {
    # passing api key only
    rewrite ^/api/([0-9\-]+)/?$ /api/index.php?apikey=$1 last;
    # passing api key and controller
    rewrite ^/api/([0-9\-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)/?$ /api/index.php?apikey=$1&controller=$2 last;
    # passing api key, controller and method
    rewrite ^/api/([0-9\-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)/((select|insert|delete)+)/?$ /api/index.php?apikey=$1&controller=$2&method=$3 last;
    # passing api key, controller, method and arguments
    rewrite ^/api/([0-9\-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)/((select|insert|delete)+)/([0-9\-]+)/?$ /api/index.php?apikey=$1&controller=$2&method=$3&argument=$4 last;
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define a rewrite rule for every API request, you will end up with a messy, hard-to-read nginx configuration file. Moreover, you will still have to define all the same routes in PHP.

Therefore, in my opinion it makes sense to have just one general purpose rewrite, eg.:

```
location /api/ {
    # passing api requests
    rewrite ^/api/(.*)/?$ /api/index.php?uri=$1 last;
}
```

And then handle all logic in index.php – parse $_REQUEST['uri'] and route accordingly. If you are redirecting everything to the same file, why implement the same logic twice?

Comment: Thank you, I will move it over to a bootstrap instead.